# Error: specified cast is not valid in rstudio

Tags: r, dataframe

I‘m running a **R** script which downloads data from a web site using a SNB API. Subsequently, I‘m loading this data into Macrobond using its API, too. I do this in **R** but when I run the script, I now get the error:

> "specified cast is not valid".

What does this mean? It somehow still downloads all the data I want from the SNB  website (I see the corresponding dataframes in **R**) but I cannot upload some of the them into Macrobond. This error only appears at the very end end after running my whole script.

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.